# Random 100 numbers in an array are increased by 1 but not sum to 100

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

My friend posted this problem on Facebook, and I don't know how it happened either.

Consider this code:

```
var num:Array = new Array();
var i:int, sum:int = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[i] = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[Math.floor(Math.random()*100)] += 1;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) sum += num[i];
trace(sum);
```

It should sum to 100, but it prints different number each time it's running, sometimes `sum` becomes greater than 100. (It's same even when `sum` has type `Number` or `*`, and `1` is changed to some other numbers such as `0.1`; the result is not close to `10.0` - something *not* like `9.9999993`.)

Meanwhile, these code are working correctly.

```
var num:Array = new Array();
var i:int, sum:int = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[i] = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[Math.floor(Math.random()*100)]++;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) sum += num[i];
trace(sum);
```

and

```
var num:Array = new Array();
var i:int, sum:int = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[i] = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    var tmp:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    num[tmp] += 1;
}
for(i=0; i<100; i++) sum += num[i];
trace(sum);
```

all correctly prints 100 all the times.

Plus, this code in JavaScript works correctly

```
var num = new Array();
var i, sum = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[i] = 0;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) num[Math.floor(Math.random()*100)] += 1;
for(i=0; i<100; i++) sum += num[i];
console.log(sum);
```

while it isn't when `console.log` is just changed to `trace` and run as an AS2 or AS3 code. What caused this behavior?

(Adobe Flash CS6 is used, and it seems that it does not matter which Flash Player is targetted (installed version is 12.0.0.38) and whether AS2 or AS3 is used; even "AIR 3.2 for Desktop" behaves equally.)

Comment: Other person on Facebook just found the reason; `a[x] += b` was compiled as `a[x] = a[x] + b` and...

Answer (score -1):

Other person on Facebook just commented on my friend's post:

```
function foo():int {
    trace("foo()");
    return 0;
}
var arr:Array = new Array();
trace("bar");
arr[foo()] = 0;
trace("bar");
arr[foo()] += 10;
```

this prints

```
bar
foo()
bar
foo()
foo()
```

, which show that when `a += b` is evaluated, `a` is evaluated twice.